# While using input:focus in input tag and changing it's size after typing text or clicking outside it;s getting back to original

Tags: css

I'm using an input tag and I changed it's size by using "focus" but after writing some text in it and clicking outside it's getting back to original size. how to fix it.

I want that the input tag change it's size and remain changed after clicking or writing text in it.

Comment: `focus` is only in effect for as long as the user keeps it selected. `focus` no longer applies when the user clicks elsewhere. Post a [mcve] of said `<input>` and I'll show you what to do to have a persistent size.